# Troubles with the xml layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created this xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".AllJokes" 
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <ListView
              android:id="@+id/allJokesList"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
            android:id="@+id/adViewContainer"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

              <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-code/code"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and it is always throwing an error, saying that the structure is not correct:

```
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

Why is this happening?

I know that it is something really small and that it have to do with the root element, but as a beginner it is hard to understand the context.

P.S: I'm adding the linearlayout after the relativelayout, because, as described in the google ads guide, there should be a space between the two elements.

Comment: Try putting the LinearLayout inside the RelativeLayout (close the container at the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurring because you have placed the `LinearLayout` outside the `RelativeLayout` which is the parent layout of `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Is there a way to leave a small gap between the `ListView` and the `RelativeLayout` ? :)

Comment: Add `android:layout_marginTop` attribute in `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Your root element here is the `RelativeLayout`, but you put the `LinearLayout` outside the root element, that's why you get this error.

If you want to have a `Linearlayout` after the `RelativeLayout`, I suggest that put another `RelativeLayout` together with your `Linearlayout` inside the root element.

Answer (score 1):

you can only have one root element for the whole XML file. Here you have two RelativeLayout and LinearLayout.